# How to show tick mark on selected picture?

Tags: android

I want to show a tick mark on the picture which is selected from gallery.
Please help me

Thanks
Monali

Answer (score 2):

You can try overriding the Gallery's `getView()` to return a `FrameLayout` which contains two `ImageViews` on top of each other (if the frame layout has more than one child it just stacks them on top if each other).

The two image views will contain:

1. the tick image (with transparent background)
2. the image

I haven't tried this, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work...

Comment: I am opening gallery using the following code             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*"); 
       
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);             Please tell me what should i do in onActivityResult

Comment: I misunderstood then... I thought you were trying to use the `Gallery`  widget to pick the image. That is what you should do if you want custom displaying of images since AFAIK you cannot customize the behavior of the ACTION_PICK Intent...

Comment: So what is the solution, should i need to use gallery widget?

Comment: Indeed, if you want a custom gallery, you should use a gallery widget and use the adapter to modify it. This is a much more complicated thing than what you were trying to do, so perhaps you should reassess if the tick mark is really worth it. Here's a tutorial to get you started: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Comment: hey monali, please tell me how u achieved this